# CodeIgniter cannot echo datetime result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, codeigniter-3

I build a website with CodeIgniter 3.1.3 and got this problem since yesterday **and I had no idea where I'm do it wrong.** It just simple get data from database with simple jQuery `$.post()` in the view to get the data and will be appended to `div`.

All data from the database table are successfully appearing, except one, the datetime!

**Model:**

```
public function get_new_kokok($option) {
    if ($option['last_showed']) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM kokok WHERE id_kokok>$option[last_showed] AND privacy=1 ORDER BY id_kokok ASC LIMIT 1");
    } else {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM kokok WHERE id_kokok=(SELECT MAX(id_kokok) FROM kokok WHERE privacy=1)");
    }
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$data = $this->model->get_new_kokok(array('last_showed'=>$this->input->post('last_showed')));

foreach($data as $kokok) {
    $id_kokok = $kokok->id_kokok;
    $id_user = $kokok->id_user;
    $kokok = $this->kokok_escape($kokok->kokok);
    $fullname = $this->model->get_userinfo('fullname',$id_user);
    $timee = $kokok->timee;
    //$time = date('h:i A',strtotime($timee));

    echo "<div class=\"clearfix\">";
    echo "<div class=\"kokokan\" data-id-kokok=\"$id_kokok\" style=\"display:none\"><p>$kokok</p><small><a href=\"".base_url()."yay/profile/$id_user\">$fullname</a> • $timee</small></div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

**I got:**

[image: Result of the first try]

The raw unformatted datetime from database ("2017-02-09 13:46:57") supposed to be appeared on the bottom-right after the name "Elena Chereishline", but it's not.

Line 25 is: `$timee = $kokok->timee;`
When I commented that line, no error happen.

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

**var_dump:**

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (11) {
        ["id_kokok"]=> string(1) "3"
        ["id_user"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["kokok"]=> string(57) "Aku punya anak lho, maksudku anak ayam :v #gaadayangnanya"
        ["react_like"]=> NULL
        ["react_love"]=> NULL
        ["react_fun"]=> NULL
        ["react_meh"]=> NULL
        ["react_mad"]=> NULL
        ["react_sad"]=> NULL
        ["privacy"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["timee"]=> string(19) "2017-02-09 13:46:57"
    }
}
```

## So my question is, what is or why this happened? How to solve this? I'm very confused _(:"3

Comment: What is on line 25 in pokopoko.php

Comment: Use `$timee->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`   and also once check with :-  `echo "<div class=\"kokokan\" data-id-kokok=\"$id_kokok\" style=\"display:none\"><p>$kokok</p><small><a href=\"".base_url()."yay/profile/$id_user\">$fullname</a>$timee</small></div>";`

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst just this line inside foreach: $timee = $kokok->timee;

Comment: Something must be going wrong here: `$kokok = $this->kokok_escape($kokok->kokok);` Remove that line and test.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst no no, that's my own function and absolutely not the problem because the kokok (post text) is succesfully appeared in the `div`. The problem is indeed the `$timee = $kokok->timee;` line. When I commented that, no error happen.

Comment: Could you update your OP with your kokok_escape() function please?

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst this is my `kokok_escape()` function:
`public function kokok_escape($kokok) { return preg_replace('/(<br \/>\s*){3,}/',' <br /> <br />',nl2br(htmlentities($kokok,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8'))); }`

Comment: Ok, inside your foreach... underneath `$kokok = $this->kokok_escape($kokok->kokok);`  write `var_dump($kokok);` and let us know the results.

Comment: Glad you're here @JethroHazelhurst! Very big thanks! :"D

Comment: No worries, glad it worked, I have provided an answer also with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `foreach` loop you are re-assigning `$kokok` which should be an object.

You are re-assigning `$kokok = $kokok->kokok`. That is a property of your object... so now when you try and access `$kokok` it is no longer the `kokok` object but rather a property of the original `kokok` object... `$kokok->kokok`.

Without knowing what your function `$this->kokok_escape();` does there is no way to help further.

You could try:

```
$kokok = $this->kokok_escape($kokok);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally **I know the answer** of my own question. Thanks to @JethroHazelhurst who very observant and noticing there's something wrong in this line:

`$kokok = $this->kokok_escape($kokok->kokok);`

Yeah, I use variable name `$kokok = ...` while `$kokok` is the variable which is used by foreach looping:

`foreach($data as $kokok) {`

So `$kokok` is messed up from array replaced with string.

Sorry and thank you to you all. :')